# Change border of mat-form-field on Angular 15

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

The image below shows the design I am after and the angular 15 output at the moment.

```
<div class="form-field-container">
   <h3>Email</h3>
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <input matInput type="email" id="Email" name="Email" formControlName="email" />
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

[image]

This is what I have tried so far to style. But none of these work. i.e. border is still rounded and the colour has to change. How do I get the border to look like the design?

```
.input {
  background-color: #E5ECF5 !important;
  color: #001050 !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

.mdc-text-field {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #001080 !important;
  background-color: #E5ECF6 !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

.mat-mdc-form-field-appearance-outline {
  border-color: #001050 !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.mat-form-field-outline-start,
.mat-form-field-outline-end {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  border-color: #001080 !important;
}

.mat-mdc-form-field-error-wrapper {
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

These are all the CSS classes from the DOM.

[image]

```
mat-mdc-form-field-subscript-wrapper mat-mdc-form-field-bottom-align ng-tns-c24-4
mat-mdc-form-field-error mat-mdc-form-field-bottom-align ng-tns-c24-4 ng-star-inserted
mat-mdc-form-field-error-wrapper ng-tns-c24-4 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted



mat-mdc-form-field ng-tns-c24-4 mat-mdc-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-outline mat-primary ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-star-inserted mat-form-field-invalid ng-touched
```

Also when I use autocomplete there is a weird back colour, but if I type it's not there.
The height of the textbox cannot be adjusted, and the text is not centred.
idealy the height should be 10px smaller and the text should be centered vertically.
[image]

Comment: Could you add an example of the generated html in your question? Would be helpful to see the resulting elements and if the CSS applies to them.

Comment: I have added it to the question.

Comment: I meant the html that gets generated from your angular code. Also, you can inspect the element and see if your rules are either overriden by other rules or if they even appear in the style of the element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The border in textfields is created by `mdc-notched-outline__leading`, `mdc-notech-outline__notch` and `mdc-noteched-outline__trailing` classes.

So, for example, you can change shape and color in this way:

```css
.mdc-notched-outline__leading, .mdc-notched-outline__notch, .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  border-color: blue !important;
}
```

Those elements are inside `<mat-form-field>` (with position absolute), that's why changing `<mat-form-field>` classes doesn't work.

Comment: that this worked. Do you know how to style on focus border style colour?

Comment: When `<mat-form-field>` is focused it gets `.mdc-text-field--focused` class, so you could use this selector: `.mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-noteched-outline__leading` (and the same for `__notch`, `__trailing`). If you want to check also for disabled state (as Angular Material does initially) you can use [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudoselector: `.mdc-text-field:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled).mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-noteched-outline__leading`

Comment: that worked like a charm. I have extended the question a bit more. If you have an idea, highly appreciate it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can modify look of autofilled inputs with [`:autofill` pseudoselector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:autofill)

Comment: I tried input:autofill, but no change. These are the css list on input at that point.
mat-mdc-input-element ng-tns-c24-4 mat-mdc-form-field-input-control mdc-text-field__input cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored cdk-text-field-autofilled ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched

Comment: Oh, as you can see, there's `cdk-text-field-autofilled` class, try to inspect its styles and overwrite to your needs.